# Mvc Jquery model value not changing dynamically

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dynamic

I have checkboxes that the user can click. When they do the value on my model isSelected changes from false to true after they click a button and the form gets posted to my controller.

EditorForModel:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsSelected)
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Publish", "Music", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    if (Model != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @Html.EditorForModel()
        }
    }

    <button class="btn btn-default" id="btn-publish" type="submit">Publish</button>
}
```

However my jquery, the value is always default (false), why is this?

```
<script>
$('#btn-publish').on('click', function (e) {
    var b_AnySelected = @Model.Any(x => x.IsSelected).ToString().ToLower();
    if (!b_AnySelected)
    {
        $('.alert').dialog('open');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Because `@Model.Any(x => x.IsSelected).ToString().ToLower();` is evaluated in server-side and when client actually checks/unchecks items the value won't change. You better go with something like `var b_AnySelected = $(this).parent('form').find('input:checked').length > 0`;

Comment: Thank you. mark you as asnwer if I could